# Limit concatenatings in group_concat

Tags: mysql

I'm just encountering an issue that i have no clue on how to solve. It is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946111/trouble-with-joining-and-the-order-of-group-concat-data) (solved) problem.

Like mentioned in the other post, i have a `Media` table that can hold up many records of the same user, but i only want to display a maximum of six records (in order, In any case, only one `Type` 1 image, followed by a maximum of five `Type` 2 images).

The query i now have works fine as long as there is only one `Type` 1 image, but when i add another `Type` 1 image, the query displays them both. Unfortunatly, something like `ORDER BY UserMedia.m_Type = 1 DESC LIMIT 1` in an `GROUP_CONCAT` doesn't work, but it is exactly what i need. Anybody a clever idea how to realise this?

I have a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86fd9/2) here with the relevant code. My query looks like this

```
SELECT
    User.u_UserName, User.u_UserMail, User.u_UserRegistration, 
        Status.us_PaymentStatus, 
        Sex.us_Gender, Sex.us_Interest, 
            Personal.up_Name, Personal.up_Dob, Personal.up_City, Personal.up_Province, 
            UserMedia.m_Id, UserMedia.m_Type, SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                GROUP_CONCAT(
                    CONCAT(
                        UserMedia.m_Type, ':', UserMedia.m_File
                    )
                    ORDER BY UserMedia.m_Type = 1, UserMedia.m_Date DESC SEPARATOR '|'
                ),'|',6
            ) AS userFiles 
FROM User AS User
    JOIN User_Status AS Status ON Status.User_u_UserId = User.u_UserId
    JOIN User_Sex_Info AS Sex ON Sex.User_u_UserId = User.u_UserId
        LEFT JOIN User_Personal_Info AS Personal ON Personal.User_u_UserId = User.u_UserId
        LEFT JOIN Media AS UserMedia ON UserMedia.User_u_UserId = User.u_UserId
WHERE User.u_UserId = '18'
    GROUP BY User.u_UserId
```

Comment: Have you looked at any of the **Related** questions?

Comment: In particular, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191815/limit-results-on-an-group-concat-or-inner-join?rq=1 seems helpful

Comment: Yes i did. I also searched for other, similar, issues but without a satisfying answer. Maybe i didn't look good enough though, i'm still looking. Edit: I overlooked that one. Reading it now

Comment: I've read it, but i'm afraid that's a bit too much for me. I have no clue on how to apply that solution to my query. I'm not that experienced enough. Can you maybe help me into the right direction?

Comment: How far do you think you're going to get if you have to get free service from the Internet every time you run into a slightly complicated piece of code? If you don't know what you're doing, you need to hire a real programmer.

Comment: I'm hoping further each time because when i understand how something works i'm learning, when i hire something i don't have to learn.

Comment: If you find the answer on your own, you should post it as an answer, not as part of the question. SO is fine with users answering there own questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went for a walk and came with the following solution. Maybe not the most beautiful one, but at least it works. I also realised i didn't need the `CONCAT` function

```
SELECT
    User.u_UserName, User.u_UserMail, User.u_UserRegistration, 
        Status.us_PaymentStatus, 
        Sex.us_Gender, Sex.us_Interest, 
            Personal.up_Name, Personal.up_Dob, Personal.up_City, Personal.up_Province, 
            UserMedia.m_Id, UserMedia.m_Type, SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                GROUP_CONCAT(
                    UserMedia.m_File
                        ORDER BY UserMedia.m_Type = 1 DESC 
                        SEPARATOR '|'
                ),'|',1
            ) AS userFiles, 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                GROUP_CONCAT(
                    UserMedia.m_File
                        ORDER BY UserMedia.m_Date DESC 
                        SEPARATOR '|'
                ),'|',5
            ) AS userTypes, 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                GROUP_CONCAT(
                    Interests.ui_Interest SEPARATOR '|'
                ),'|',5
            ) AS userInterests
FROM User AS User
    JOIN User_Status AS Status ON Status.User_u_UserId = User.u_UserId
    JOIN User_Sex_Info AS Sex ON Sex.User_u_UserId = User.u_UserId
        LEFT JOIN User_Personal_Info AS Personal ON Personal.User_u_UserId = User.u_UserId
        LEFT JOIN Media AS UserMedia ON UserMedia.User_u_UserId = User.u_UserId
        LEFT JOIN User_Interest_Info AS Interests ON Interests.User_u_UserId = User.u_UserId
WHERE User.u_UserId = :uId
    GROUP BY User.u_UserId
```